# Can I use PS3 / PS4 controller on iOS 7?

Tags: controllers, ios

Since, evasi0n iOS7 is already out and we all know that iOS 7 already has Gaming Controller support or APIs, I'm wondering if there is some sort of Cydia tweak that is already out / under-development to make the PS3 / PS4 controller compatible with iOS 7.

I have an iPad and I think playing Bastion with a PS4 controller in it would be super cool!!!

Answer (score 1):

There is already one tweak called **Controllers for All** on Cydia. It works with all games with MFi Controller support.

Unfortunately, it only supports the PS3 controller right now but the developer promised that more controllers will be supported on future updates, including the PS4.

It is 1.99$ on Big Boss repo. Go get!

Source:

[Controllers for All: a must have tweak that brings PS3 controller compatibility to iOS](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2014/01/19/controllers-for-all-a-must-have-tweak-that-brings-ps3-controller-compatibility-to-ios/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this guy has a video explaining how to get the tweek "Controllers For All" to work:

Each application is programed to enable support for a controller. So this will only work for certain applications.

---

To make sure the future readers of this post can access this information regardless if the youtube video exists or not, below is a summary of what the video above explains:

- In order to use a PS3/4 controller with an iOS device you must first jailbreak it.
- There is no way to use a PS3/4 controller natively as of 9-23-14.
- After you have jailbroken your device*, you should download the tweak 'Controllers   for All' from Cydia.
- Next, you will need to pair your controller to your device. Follow these steps:

  - Plug your controller and iOS device into your Computer via USB.
  - Download a program called 'SixPair' by going to this site: http://orikad.com/sixpair_instructions.html or Googling it if this link is broken.
  - Start SixPair and pair your device.
  - DONE!
- Turn off your Bluetooth.
- Go to settings>BTstack (this will install once you install the tweek) and check 'BTstack'.
  -Enjoy using your PS3/4 controller to play controller enabled games!!!

Answer (score -1):

Yes blutrol. It is only compatible with ios 6 as of now. But is under development to work with ios 7